# QPlainTextEdit text alignment

Tags: qt

The following code works for QTextEdit , but it doesn't work for QPlainTextEdit:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->plainTextEdit->clear();
ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("example");
ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("example");
QTextCursor cursor = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();
QTextBlockFormat textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat();
textBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);
ui->plainTextEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);

ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("example");

cursor = ui->plainTextEdit->textCursor();
textBlockFormat = cursor.blockFormat();
textBlockFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
cursor.mergeBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);
ui->plainTextEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

I am expecting the alignment of the appended text to change but it is not.

Comment: `QPlainTextEdit` doesn't support such alignment.

Comment: does alighnment come as a rich text feature only ?